# Simple html/css challange for learning purposes

Tags: beginner, html, bem

As part of my study, I decided to do [this task from frontendmentor site](https://www.frontendmentor.io/challenges/social-proof-section-6e0qTv_bA). It's a short html code but I would like to learn good practices from the beginning.

The problem I had encountered:

- Adding names to classes to make them readable
- What should I pay attention to when making the page accessibility

In the code below I tried to use the BEM method and html semantically.

I was wondering if I could get some good critique on my HTML code and learn some best practices while I'm at it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    

    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="32x32"
      href="./images/favicon-32x32.png"
    />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Spartan:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <title>Frontend Mentor | Social proof section</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1 class="header__heading">10,000+ of our users love our productds.</h1>
      <p class="header__text">We only provide great products combined with excellent customer service. See what our satisfied customers are saying about our services.</p>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div class="rating">
        <div class="rating__stars">
          <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="star">
          <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="star">
          <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="star">
          <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="star">
          <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="star">
        </div>
        <p class="rating__info">Reated 5 Stars in Reviews</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rating">
        <div class="rating__stars">
          <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="star">
          <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="star">
          <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="star">
          <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="star">
          <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="star">
        </div>
        <p class="rating__info">Reated 5 Stars in Reviews</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rating">
        <div class="rating__stars">
          <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="star">
          <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="star">
          <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="star">
          <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="star">
          <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="star">
        </div>
        <p class="rating__info">Reated 5 Stars in Reviews</p>
      </div>

      <section class="reviews">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card__img" src="./images/image-colton.jpg" alt="Colton Smith avatar">
          <h2 class="card__name">Colton Smith</h2>
          <span class="card__role">Verified Buyer</span>
          <p class="card__text">"We needed the same printed design as the one we had ordered a aweek prior. Not only did they find the orginal order, but we also received it in time Excellent!"</p>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <img class="card__img" src="./images/image-colton.jpg" alt="Irene Roberts avatar">
          <h2 class="card__name">Irene Roberts</h2>
          <span class="card__role">Verified Buyer</span>
          <p class="card__text">"Customer service is always excellent and very quick turn around. Completeely delighted with the simplicity of the purchase and the speed of delivery."</p>
        </div>


        <div class="card">
          <img class="card__img" src="./images/image-colton.jpg" alt="Anne Wallace avatar">
          <h2 class="card__name">Anne Wallace</h2>
          <span class="card__role">Verified Buyer</span>
          <p class="card__text">"Put an order with this company and can only praise them for the very high standard. Will defenitely use them again and recommend them to everyone"</p>
        </div>

      </section>
    </main>

  </body>
</html>
```